# Is there any way to get MYSQL command suggestions inside java statement?

Tags: mysql, netbeans

Hi I am working on this project but I'm in a hurry. It's really annoying to copy MySQL table and column names, especially when I join them. I use netbeans 8.0.2 so I am wondering is there anyway to get MySQL command suggestions in my statement String area?

Comment: Can you add a MySQL datasource in Netbeans which will connect to the server and then work it out from there?

Comment: i can. but i want it to be done inside the statement string ex :  ResultSet rs = DB.DB.search("INSERT INTO stock (id, item, qty) VALUES (1,12,20)"); i need it to be done inside "" (curly brackets )

Comment: Whatever you type inside a string that is text and any development environment will treat it as such, so you will not have code completion there. You may choose to have another development environment for developing  sql statements, which does have code completion for sql statements as well and then you just copy over the text into your java environment.

Comment: @Shadow is that so.. yeah i use netbeans for mysql. thanx a lot mate.